# Using Excel Page Breaks to Create Multiple PDFs

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I have a workbook that's broken up exactly how I'd like with regards to page breaks (from using Subtotals), but obviously that all goes into one PDF -- which means to send it out, I'd have to manually split it up and re-save each person's lists amongst 100+ employees.

Is there any way that I can group them to export as an individual PDF per employee, if there's a unique value in each cell for the employee in the spreadsheet?

So basically my page breaks are currently exactly how I'd like them -- but if there's 60 cells (all already ordered/grouped together) from B2:B61 that say "John Smith" for employee, make those 60 rows one PDF (page broken within that PDF how it's currently laid out), then if the next 25 cells from B62:B87 say "Jane Smith" for employee, make that one PDF with its current page breaks, etc.

Is something like this possible? Maybe using VBA?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a sample of data -- I'm using Excel with subtotals in Column C, which is how to get the page breaks where I'd like them at the change in each group. I just use Print >> Save to PDF to make my PDF. Everything works well, except while the page breaks are at every change in Group -- I'd like to somehow have Excel spit out separate PDFs based on what's in Column D. Here's the [spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/frt87yjlessfonk/PDFGroupSample.xlsx?dl=0). (Even though Dropbox seemingly removes the current page breaks, which is just every time there's a change in Column C.)

Comment: Run the code in my answer changing dCol to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within VBA you have access to a number of properties to manage page breaks.

[Range.PageBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193644(v=office.15).aspx) returns or sets a page break, so you could manage your page breaks programatically with respect to your employee counts.

[Worksheet.HPageBreaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193761(v=office.15).aspx) and [Worksheet.VPageBreaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195715(v=office.15).aspx) give you access to the horizontal and vertical page breaks collection.

So `Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Count` for example, will give yuo the number of horizontal page breaks in your worksheet.

`Worksheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Row` will give you the position of the first horizontal page break and similarly `Worksheet.VPageBreaks(1).Location.Column` will give you the location of the first vertical page break.

These tools coupled with a `.Find` or two should allow you to describe the range(s) to be produced as .pdf and allow you to accomplish what you require.

**EDIT with starter code sample following OP comment**

Having re-read your post this starter code produces two .pdf files based on your original Q.  I have set page length to be 50 lines - this is sensitive to font size, paper size, margins etc.  You need to provide your own 'outputPath' to save your files.  Example runs on a single column of data.

It's a starter so no warranties with this, and be aware that when the code runs, all manual page breaks will be removed (.ResetAllPageBreaks).

```
Option Base 1
Sub pdf()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dArr() As String, outputPath As String, fileStem As String
Dim dCol As Long, stRow As Long, endRow As Long, pStRow As Long
Dim docCnt As Long, lnCnt As Long
Dim rwsPerPage As Integer, topM As Integer, botM As Integer
Dim empNme As String

Set ws = Sheets("Data")
dCol = 2    'col B
stRow = 2   'row 2

pStRow = stRow
rwsPerPage = 50
topM = 36   'default in points
botM = 36   'default in points
outputPath = "<yourpath>\"
fileStem = "Employee "

docCnt = 1
lnCnt = 0

    With ws
        'set essential page parameters
        With .PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .TopMargin = topM
            .BottomMargin = botM
        End With
        .ResetAllPageBreaks

        'last data row
        endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Row
        'first employee name
        empNme = .Cells(stRow, dCol)

            'for each data row
            For c = stRow To endRow
                lnCnt = lnCnt + 1

                    'at change of employee name
                    If Not .Cells(c, dCol).Value = empNme Then
                        'put doc range into array
                        ReDim Preserve dArr(docCnt)
                        dArr(docCnt) = .Range(.Cells(pStRow, dCol), .Cells(c - 1, dCol)).Address
                        docCnt = docCnt + 1
                        'reset startrow of new employee
                        pStRow = c
                        empNme = .Cells(c, dCol).Value
                        'add hpage break
                        .HPageBreaks.Add before:=.Cells(c, dCol)
                        lnCnt = 0
                    End If

                    'at page length
                    If lnCnt = rwsPerPage Then
                        'add hpage break
                        .HPageBreaks.Add before:=.Cells(lnCnt, dCol)
                        lnCnt = 0
                    End If
            Next c

            'last employee if appropriate to array
            If c - 1 > pStRow Then
                ReDim Preserve dArr(docCnt)
                dArr(docCnt) = .Range(.Cells(pStRow, dCol), .Cells(c, dCol)).Address
            End If

            'produce pdf files
            For d = 1 To UBound(dArr, 1)
                .Range(dArr(d)).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    outputpat & fileStem & d & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=True
            Next d

    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT #2 with starter code sample using OP data and correcting a typo in the outputPath**

```
Option Base 1
Sub pdf()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dArr() As String, outputPath As String, fileStem As String
Dim dCol As Long, stRow As Long, endRow As Long, pStRow As Long
Dim docCnt As Long, lnCnt As Long
Dim rwsPerPage As Integer, topM As Integer, botM As Integer
Dim empNme As String

Set ws = Sheets("Data")
dCol = 4    'col D
stRow = 2   'row 2

pStRow = stRow
rwsPerPage = 50
topM = 36   'default in points
botM = 36   'default in points
outputPath = "<yourpath>\"
fileStem = "Employee "

docCnt = 1
lnCnt = 0

    With ws
        'set essential page parameters
        With .PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .TopMargin = topM
            .BottomMargin = botM
        End With
        .ResetAllPageBreaks

        'last data row
        endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Row
        'first employee name
        empNme = .Cells(stRow, dCol)

            'for each data row
            For c = stRow To endRow
                lnCnt = lnCnt + 1

                    'at change of employee name
                    If Not .Cells(c, dCol).Value = empNme Then
                        'put doc range into array
                        ReDim Preserve dArr(docCnt)
                        dArr(docCnt) = .Range(.Cells(pStRow, dCol - 3), .Cells(c - 1, dCol - 1)).Address
                        docCnt = docCnt + 1
                        'reset startrow of new employee
                        pStRow = c
                        empNme = .Cells(c, dCol).Value
                        'add hpage break
                        .HPageBreaks.Add before:=.Cells(c, dCol)
                        lnCnt = 0
                    End If

                    'at page length
                    If lnCnt = rwsPerPage Then
                        'add hpage break
                        .HPageBreaks.Add before:=.Cells(lnCnt, dCol)
                        lnCnt = 0
                    End If
            Next c

            'last employee if appropriate to array
            If c - 1 > pStRow Then
                ReDim Preserve dArr(docCnt)
                dArr(docCnt) = .Range(.Cells(pStRow, dCol - 3), .Cells(c - 1, dCol - 1)).Address
            End If

            'produce pdf files
            For d = 1 To UBound(dArr, 1)
                .Range(dArr(d)).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    outputPath & fileStem & d & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=True
            Next d

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I were better at writing VBA to put something like this together -- is there any way you could put together some preliminary code on how this would look that I could play with?

Comment: It's probably not that easy to describe I appreciate, but we do need a bit more info.  Can you provide a representative sample of your data to work with, the criteria you need to apply and your expected output. How were you intending to produce the .pdf files?

Comment: Thanks so much! Check out my edit above -- I added a bit more info and a sample spreadsheet to work with. Hope that helps! Thanks again.

Comment: Code amended to use your data and 'print out' the first three columns of your data.  In actual fact you don't need to worry about  positioning your own actual page breaks, just use a change of string in your column D to differentiate your data?  Don't forget to supply your own outputPath in the code.

Comment: Sorry this took a little bit to test -- and also sorry that I'm not very well-versed in macros. But when I change the output and attempt to run, I get a "Subscript Out of Range" error. Is there something else I need to be editing?

Comment: No problem Ryan, I'm happy to help you chase it down.  Presumably, you are using the Edit #2 code?  It would be helpful to know which line it errors-out, but a 'usual suspect' in this case will be an array subscript.  When it errors take a note of the line number and the value(s) of 'c' (how many times has it looped) and 'docCnt', for starters.  Also how did you change 'change the output'?

Comment: Thanks a lot -- I'm using the second code and I changed the output to '/Users/Ryan/Desktop' (I'm using a Mac).

Comment: OK Ryan, the Mac bit was a crucial bit of information so thank you.  The filepath on a Mac is described differently to Windows so start by changing the line outputPath = "<yourpath>\" and replace "\" with ":".  So my line reads outputpath = "untitled:users:<myname>:desktop:". I had to quote the whole path including the name of the disk/volume which on my MacBook at the moment is 'untitled' (I suppose I should rename it really).  Yours may be different.  With that mod it runs OK on my MacBook.

Comment: Thanks. I changed mine to "Macintosh HD:Users:Ryan:Desktop:" -- is the space a problem? I'm still getting the "Subscript Out of Range" error.

Comment: OK softly, softly.  Is your Sheet called "Data"? If not change the line "Set ws = Sheets("Data")" to your sheet name.

Comment: Ah, that was it! Was still called "Sheet1." Can't believe I missed that. This is great, though! Thanks so much. I think I  just have one more thing. Currently this creates PDFs split up by Column D perfectly to my output path (which is great) -- though the ultimate goal was to use Column C (the distinct groups) to page break _within_ that PDF. So, for example, on the "Employee 1" PDF, instead of one page, there would be two pages within the same PDF: one page with all of "Group A" then a second page with all of "Group B" within the "Employee 1" PDF. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well done Ryan, glad you are nearly there.  Now, this thread is getting longer than it should.  May I suggest that you take a view on whether this answer has answered your original Q and if so accept it appropriately and then open another Q with your 'new' requirement.  In the meantime I (for one) will have a look at your 'new' requirement. This will prevent extended discussions, chunk up your requirements making them easier to follow and make sure you get a breadth of expertise to look at/assist in your final solution.

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks again for all the help. And sorry I wasn't as clear as I should've been in my initial question on the output.

Comment: Here's the new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895249/excel-vba-to-create-page-breaks-by-grouping-within-multiple-pdfs